# MySQL Select From To And Exclude m in returned id result

Tags: mysql, between

I have SQL that returns this from MySQL:

```
SELECT id, channel, (y.count) AS channels
FROM (
    SELECT s.id AS id, c.sort, s.channel
    FROM channels c, streams s
    LEFT JOIN logo l ON s.id=l.channel
    WHERE JSON_SEARCH(s.bouquet, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL 
    AND JSON_SEARCH(c.bouquet, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL
    AND JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', s.id) IS NOT NULL

    UNION 

    SELECT m.marker, c.sort, m.channel
    FROM markers m, channels c, streams s
    LEFT JOIN logo l ON s.id=l.channel
    WHERE JSON_SEARCH(m.bouquet, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL 
    AND JSON_SEARCH(c.bouquet, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL
    AND JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', m.marker) IS NOT NULL
    AND s.id=l.channel) ch
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT count
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(s.id RLIKE '^[0-9]+$') AS count
        FROM streams s, channels c 
        WHERE JSON_SEARCH(s.bouquet, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL 
        AND JSON_SEARCH(c.bouquet, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL 
        AND JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', s.id) IS NOT NULL) AS x) AS y
ORDER BY LOCATE(CONCAT('"', id, '"'), sort);
```

Return From This Query is:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | channel           |
+----+-------------------+
| m2 | AA-AA             |
| 1  | KR_A 1            |
| 2  | KR_A 2            |
| 11 | HR_A 3            |
| 12 | HR_B 1            |
| m4 | BB-BB             |
| m3 | CC-CC             |
| 17 | SR_B 1            |
| m5 | DD-DD             |
| m1 | EE-EE             |
+----+-------------------+
```

I need to modify SQL to when i add `m2` in Query to return:

```
1
2
11
12
```

And if i add `m3` i need to get:

```
17
```

So i try to add this in beginning of SQL to filter id:

```
SELECT IF (id BETWEEN 'm2' AND '%m', id, 0) As id, channel, (y.count) AS channels
```

and i get this:

```
+----+-------------------+----------+
| id | channel           | channels |
+----+-------------------+----------+
| m2 | AA-AA             |        5 |
| 0  | KR_A 1            |        5 |
| 0  | KR_A 2            |        5 |
| 0  | HR_A 3            |        5 |
| 0  | HR_B 1            |        5 |
| m4 | BB-BB             |        5 |
| m3 | CC-CC             |        5 |
| 0  | SR_B 1            |        5 |
| m5 | DD-DD             |        5 |
| m1 | EE-EE             |        5 |
+----+-------------------+----------+
```

And need to get this:

```
+----+-------------------+----------+
| id | channel           | channels |
+----+-------------------+----------+
| 1  | KR_A 1            |        4 |
| 2  | KR_A 2            |        4 |
| 11 | HR_A 3            |        4 |
| 12 | HR_B 1            |        4 |
+----+-------------------+----------+
```

I don't know how to do in SQL query that select from `'m2'` to next `'m'` and exclude `'m2'` and `'m'` from results....any help?

Comment: I'm confused on what you are trying to accomplish, but can't you just put a `Where id not like 'm%'` on the outer part of the query?

Comment: No i need only to put it into beggining of SELECT id.... because i need to get above example data from table, so how to do in MySQL query begin to fetch data from 'm2' to next 'm', and exclude from returned data 'm2' and next 'm'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to save if the previous row was the desired marker (when the `id` starts with '*m*') or if the `id` is after desired marker (when id not starts with '*m*' and the flag (`@showRow`) is active)

```
SET @showRow:=0;
SELECT id, channel, (y.count) AS channels...
...
 WHERE 
     (
       @showRow:=( (id like 'm%' and id = 'm2') or (id not like 'm%' and @showRow ) )
      )
   -- ommit marker row
   AND id not like 'm%'
;
```